# Lua Compare Multiple Table Values

Tags: string, lua, compare

Hello I have a Table like

```
list[i].font_name
```

i is an undefined number, I want to parse trough the table and compare if any have the same string. Then change the string

Like

```
if list[1].font_name == list[2].font_name then  
  list[2].font_name = list[2].font_name..'2'
end
```

There can be more than one match like

```
list[1].font_name
list[2].font_name
list[3].font_name
```

.
Thanks all you for the time to answer question on the web :) Merry Xmas

Comment: and what is your question? you seem to know how to check if two values are equal. and the trivial task of traversing a table is explained in any Lua tutorial/book out there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a hash table to count the number of times you see each font_name and loop through the `list`. This works, because if two values compare as equal (without a metamethod), they are considered the same key.

```
-- This keeps track of duplicates.
local counter = {}

for i, v in ipairs(list) do
  local font = v.font_name

  -- Increment the count for this font.
  local count = (counter[font] or 0) + 1
  counter[font] = count

  if count > 1 then
    v.font_name = font .. count
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks Luther For answering me, it works :) 

I before made another solution with two for loops that then compares every item on the table and if it found an duplicate it renames. 

As yours use just one for loop I thought it would be faster, but I benchmark it and surprisingly it went slower than two for loops . 

Any way I will keep that trick in mind thanks !!!  :)